# Modify an EF entity in the object context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to write an EF command which will fix one of it's fields if it gets an exception on SaveChanges().  Please refer to the following code sample:

```
        model.IMAGES.AddObject(new IMAGES
            {
                IMAGE = imageByteArray,
                IMAGE_NAME = pNum + "_OTHER.JPG",
                VIEWPOINT_ID = 279,
                ID_NO = ++id,
            });
        try
        {
            model.SaveChanges();
            Trace.WriteLine("Saved: " + pNum + "_OTHER.JPG");
        }
        catch
        {
            model.REF_PART_IMAGES.Last().VIEWPOINT_ID = 272;
            model.SaveChanges();
            Trace.WriteLine("Saved: " + pNum + "_OTHER.JPG");                
        }
```

The call to Last() throws "**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'PullPics.IMAGES LastIMAGES' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**"

Does anyone have ideas on how to access the newly created object to modify it?

Comment: Why not check the Last() VIEWPOINT_ID before calling SaveChanges()?  Generally it's not good to condition based upon try/catch: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/107723/arguments-for-or-against-using-try-catch-as-logical-operators

Comment: However, if your error still persists after moving it before SaveChanges() We'll need to see all the relevant parts of your model.

Comment: you have some query in the Last() method that throws that exception. You cannot use custom methods in query expression. Fetch items to memory before (for instance toArray) if result set isn't very big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I don't want Last(), I just want to keep a reference to the original object and update that:

```
    var image = new IMAGES
        {
            IMAGE = imageByteArray,
            IMAGE_NAME = pNum + "_OTHER.JPG",
            VIEWPOINT_ID = 279,
            ID_NO = ++id,
        };

    model.IMAGES.AddObject(image);
    try
    {
        model.SaveChanges();
        Trace.WriteLine("Saved: " + pNum + "_OTHER.JPG");
    }
    catch
    {
        image.VIEWPOINT_ID = 272;
        model.SaveChanges();
        Trace.WriteLine("Saved: " + pNum + "_OTHER.JPG");                
    }
```